# Field mapping for HTML

Tags: solr, nutch

I am now to Solr and Nutch. I have a question on the field mapping in solr / nutch schema.xml. I want solr/nutch pickup some keywords from one of my website. I know that the schema.xml has a field mapping section to allow me to do so. What I want to know is how should I put the keyword field in the HTML ? Should I just hte HTML hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="keyword" .... />
```

Or should I use the

```
<meta/>
```

tag ?

Answer (score 1):

There was work done on [extracting element from HTML by XPATH](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-978), so you can check on it.

However, using meta tags can be a better option as the html pages are usually malformed for the xpath expression. You can use [Index Metatags](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/IndexMetatags) with Nutch to extract the metatag and populate the fields in Solr.